# Android: How to inspect or debug the spans inside the TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I'm creating a `CharSequence` with differently styled text spans(italic, bold, hyperlink, etc.,) and setting it on a `TextView`.

It is working as expected in all the other screens except one.
In that one screen alone, `hyperlink` font is working fine but not the other styled spans.

Is there any way to debug or inspect the **textview** to find out the spans set inside ?

Comment: use `Android Device Monitor`

Comment: see `TextUtils` javadocs

Answer (score 0):

As @pskink gave me the hint, I had found the way to debug the spans inside the `CharSequence` using `TextUtils.dumpSpans()`

It works cool, shows the span object with start, end positions and flags too.